# FindMeetingTimes with TimeConstraint returns ErrorInternalServerError

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Using Graph API I am positing a request similar to below.

For some reason, when I include the `TimeConstraint` I get a null pointer. If I don't include the `TimeConstraint` node, request is returned successfully.

To me, my `TimeConstraint` section looks OK. Is there anything wrong or that I'm missing?

Exception:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "905b8b0f-5de2-4559-861d-4244aa25da7c",
      "date": "2017-11-21T13:48:32"
    }
  }
}
```

Request:

```
{
   "Attendees":[
      {
         "type":"required",
         "emailAddress":{
            "address":"user1@tenant.com"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"required",
         "emailAddress":{
            "address":"user2@tenant.com"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"required",
         "emailAddress":{
            "address":"user3@tenant.com"
         }
      }
   ],
   "LocationConstraint":{
      "locations":[
         {
            "resolveAvailability":true,
            "locationEmailAddress":"room@tenant.com"
         }
      ]
   },
   "TimeConstraint":{
      "activityDomain":"work",
      "timeslots":[
         {
            "start":{
               "dateTime":"2017-11-26T09:00:00",
               "timeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"
            }
         },
         {
            "end":{
               "dateTime":"2017-11-26T17:00:00",
               "timeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "MeetingDuration":"PT1H",
   "MaxCandidates":99,
   "IsOrganizerOptional":false,
   "ReturnSuggestionReasons":true,
   "MinimumAttendeePercentage":100.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start`and`end` properties are scoped one level too far. These are properties of the same object:

Try this instead:

```json
"timeslots": [{
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-11-23T16:58:07.973Z",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-11-30T16:58:07.973Z",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    }
}]
```

When using the Microsoft Graph .NET Client SDK:

```cs
// Create TimeConstraint
TimeConstraint timeConstraint = new TimeConstraint();
timeConstraint.ActivityDomain = ActivityDomain.Unrestricted;

// Create a TimeSlot
TimeSlot timeSlot = new TimeSlot();
timeSlot.Start.DateTime = "2017-11-23T16:58:07.973Z";
timeSlot.Start.TimeZone = "Eastern Standard Time";
timeSlot.End.DateTime = "2017-11-30T16:58:07.973Z";
timeSlot.End.TimeZone = "Eastern Standard Time";

// Create a TimeSlot collection and add the TimeSlot
List<TimeSlot> timeSlots = new List<TimeSlot>();
timeSlots.Add(timeSlot);

// Assign the TimeSlot collection to the TimeContraint
timeConstraint.Timeslots = timeSlots;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated (any my question) to include activityDomain and am still receiving a null pointer.

Comment: anymore thoughts here?

Comment: I'm wondering if it might be related to the timeZone. If you enter the time as UTC, does that have any effect?

Comment: Doesn't appear so. Here is what my exact TimeConstraint looks like. Not sure what else to do as I know removing TC produces a successful request.  "TimeConstraint":{"activityDomain":"work","timeslots":[{"start":{"dateTime":"2017-11-23T09:00:00","timeZone":"UTC"}},{"end":{"dateTime":"2017-11-23T17:00:00","timeZone":"UTC"}}]}

Comment: are you able to do a FindMeetingTimes request with a time constraint on your end? Just trying to narrow things down at this point. Thanks!

Comment: I found it and updated my answer. You had an extra object encapsulating `start` and `end`

Comment: Hmm not following. I'm using the SDK so it should populate the request correctly. See image https://s18.postimg.org/5s9pdidvd/2017-11-23_14-50-45.png

Comment: `Start` and `End` are properties of the same `TimeSlot`, not separate `TimeSlot` objects. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: makes sense! thanks for the updated answer... working now! terrible error message :)